# What does negative homoegenous coordinates signify?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

What do negative homogeneous coordinates signify? Why are they not useful in bi-linear interpolation of image A onto the plane of another image B?

Homogeneous coordinates can be calculated as follows:

[image]

But I am unable to understand what do negative homogeneous coordinates mean!?

During the interpolation process, I tried to use both negative and positive homogeneous coordinates and then only positive homogeneous coordinates. With positive homogeneous coordinates, projection worked as expected but with negative and positive projection didn't work well and the image that was being projected onto another image occupied the whole part in the output image.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have [two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54753917/5008845)?